# Scale elements proportionally to the screen size

Tags: android, scaling

my button on the Nexus S (480x800) looks pretty good. It takes a bit less than a fourth of the screen's height. When I open my app on the Nexus 10 (2560x1600) the botton seems to be a lot smaller.
I'm looking for a way where my button is scaling correctly proportionally to the screen size. So that my button takes even on the Nexus 10 the same room of the empty screen as it does on the Nexus S. 
I know that there are drawable folders, but they aren't solving my problem correctly. For example: The Nexus 10 and the Galaxy Nexus are both xhdpi. The screen of the Nexus 10 is way bigger though. So my button would take different amounts of room on these devices.

Thanks !

Comment: The correct folder for Nexus 10 would be **drawable-sw1600dp** and for the Nexus S **drawable-hdpi**

Comment: Ok, but I'm sure there are more different resolutions than different drawable folders. So is there an alternative way  ?

Comment: normally, for PHONES, you follow the rule drawable-XYZdpi (XYZ = l|m|h|xh|xxh|xxxh) and for TABLETS drawable-swZYXdp (ZYX being the minor width in px, so: ..., 1024, 1280, 1600, ...). There are a limited number of tablet resolutions, as well as phone resolutions.

Comment: What would you then if the button isn't based on an image. Just a normal button. Image files wouldn't have any impact on that element.

Comment: I'd anyway use dp/sp as unit measures. And I'd use the values folders for dimensions. Using **values-sw1600dp** in your case. So the size of the fonts would be sized to my taste for each resolution.

Comment: But there are even less values folders than drawable folders to cover every resolution

Comment: There are as many folders as you make. More or less it depends on what you provide.

Comment: Ok so If I'd create a folder called "values-hdpi" Android would recognize it and use it with the drawable-hdpi folder ? I was hoping there was a way to set the size of certain elements like a button percental to the screen size. That would make it a lot easier IMO

Comment: I agree, it would. but percents are not an option, in Android. There's a workaround for that (1 dimension - width or height) at a time: It's called **weight** and it's only usable by the children of a layout that inherits from LinearLayout (such as RadioGroup, TableRow, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You have got two options here

**1. Effective use of Drawable Folders**
The various drawable folders have a *dimension* and *density* parameter associated with them. For example these are the variations as per dimension parameter: ldpi=240X320, mdpi=320X480 hdpi=480X800 and like wise. And the other parameter is density: mdpi: 160 dpi, hdpi: 240-dpi, xhdpi: 320-dpi.

You will need to design images in PhotoShop keeping these parameters in mind and then place the corrosponding images into appropriate drawable variant(drawable-large-ldpi, drawable-xlarge-mdpi etc). I mean, in photoShop or some other image editing software, you will need to specify pixel-density and dimension parameter for the drawing canvas(as per above), and then create images on that canvas.
(Hope you understand what I mean:)

**2. Programatically Scale the images**
I have stumbled upon image scaling problem a number of times in my projects and each time due to lack of time (and laziness) I would be satisfied with a less than optimum solution. But recently I found some time to crack down this particular issue. Here is my solution and I hope it helps you as well.

```
Bitmap scaleDownLargeImageWithAspectRatio(Bitmap image)
        {
            int imaheVerticalAspectRatio,imageHorizontalAspectRatio;
            float bestFitScalingFactor=0;
            float percesionValue=(float) 0.2;

            //getAspect Ratio of Image
            int imageHeight=(int) (Math.ceil((double) image.getHeight()/100)*100);
            int imageWidth=(int) (Math.ceil((double) image.getWidth()/100)*100);
            int GCD=BigInteger.valueOf(imageHeight).gcd(BigInteger.valueOf(imageWidth)).intValue();
            imaheVerticalAspectRatio=imageHeight/GCD;
            imageHorizontalAspectRatio=imageWidth/GCD;
            Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","Image Dimensions(W:H): "+imageWidth+":"+imageHeight);
            Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","Image AspectRatio(W:H): "+imageHorizontalAspectRatio+":"+imaheVerticalAspectRatio);

            //getContainer Dimensions
            int displayWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            int displayHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
           //I wanted to show the image to fit the entire device, as a best case. So my ccontainer dimensions were displayWidth & displayHeight. For your case, you will need to fetch container dimensions at run time or you can pass static values to these two parameters 

            int leftMargin = 0;
            int rightMargin = 0;
            int topMargin = 0;
            int bottomMargin = 0;
            int containerWidth = displayWidth - (leftMargin + rightMargin);
            int containerHeight = displayHeight - (topMargin + bottomMargin);
            Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","Container dimensions(W:H): "+containerWidth+":"+containerHeight);

            //iterate to get bestFitScaleFactor per constraints
            while((imageHorizontalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor <= containerWidth) && 
                    (imaheVerticalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor<= containerHeight))
            {
                bestFitScalingFactor+=percesionValue;
            }

            //return bestFit bitmap
            int bestFitHeight=(int) (imaheVerticalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor);
            int bestFitWidth=(int) (imageHorizontalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor);
            Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","bestFitScalingFactor: "+bestFitScalingFactor);
            Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","bestFitOutPutDimesions(W:H): "+bestFitWidth+":"+bestFitHeight);
            image=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, bestFitWidth,bestFitHeight, true);

            //Position the bitmap centre of the container
            int leftPadding=(containerWidth-image.getWidth())/2;
            int topPadding=(containerHeight-image.getHeight())/2;
            Bitmap backDrop=Bitmap.createBitmap(containerWidth, containerHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            Canvas can = new Canvas(backDrop);
            can.drawBitmap(image, leftPadding, topPadding, null);

            return backDrop;
        }
```